# STLExporter Three.js Issue

Tags: three.js, 3d

I have the following code to export my STL file but it doesn't seems to work.

```
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.load( './Mr_Jaws.stl', function ( geometry ) {
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x0692CE, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 100 } );

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.scale.set( 1.2, 1.2, 1.2 );
mesh.castShadow = true;
mesh.receiveShadow = true;
mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );

var box = new THREE.BoxHelper( mesh );
scene.add( box );
scene.add( mesh );

var export_stl = new THREE.STLExporter();
console.log(export_stl.parse(mesh));
});
```

What I get is the following:

solid exported

endsolid exported

Hope you can help me out.

Three.js version

```
Dev
[X ] r76
...
```